# The Pitiable Coder - Edition 2

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story, anagram, science

It had been a while since my favourite newspaper had published any puzzles. In fact, it had been so long since ['The Pitiable Coder' released $\mathbb{CHEMICRYPTICS}$](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48933/the-pitiable-coder), that I was beginning to think that they had forgotten about them completely!

But then yesterday, I opened up the paper and to my delight found a puzzle column! This time it had 3 new puzzles!!!

I wonder if you could help me find the answer? Here's the puzzles from the paper:

$$\boxed{
\phantom{x}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \huge\text{Welcome to another edition of }\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \huge\mathbb{CHEMICRYPTICS}\\ 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \underline{\text{Except this time there's more!}}\\
\phantom{x}\\
\sf\text{In the last edition, we promised the introduction of 2 new types, } \mathbb{BIOCRYPTICS }\\ \text{ and }\ \mathbb{ PHYSICRYPTICS} \text{, and we are happy to introduce all three of them today}\\  \text{in one big}\
\text{meta-puzzle!}\\
\text{ }\\
\text{Each individual puzzle will give you a one word answer, and putting all three}\\ \text{together will lead you to}\
\text{the answer to the final question:}\\
\phantom{x}\\
\text{'What do I, the self-critical author, think of this puzzle?'.}\\
\phantom{x}\\
\text{Once again, we aren't going to tell you how any of these work, that's for you}\\
 \text{to work out. A}\
\text{reminder that these aren't cryptic clues, and our own invention.}\\
\phantom{x}\\
\text{Good luck!!}
\phantom{x}\\
\phantom{x}\\
\begin{array}{l|l|l}
\hline
\\
\ \ \ \mathbb{\color{green}{BIOCRYPTICS}} &\ \ \ \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \mathbb{\color{purple}{CHEMICRYPTICS}}&\ \ \ \ \mathbb{\color{navy}{PHYSICRYPTICS}} \ \ \ \ \\
\\
\hline
\ \ &\ \ &\ \\
\small\text{P3 of Emanate } \ &\ \small\text{A ringtone followed by an umber lily} \ &\ \small\text{A Gerbil OBE is French}\\
\small\text{C6 of Maniac} \ &\ \small\text{A burly lime precedes a foul rein} \ &\ \small\text{The Nineties are German}\\
\small\text{F5 of Paroled} \ &\ \small\text{A grin note} \ &\ \small\text{Hulls are American}\\
\small\text{O4 of Throne} \ &\ \small\text{A con bar with e.g. onyx} \ &\ \small\text{A Hornet is American}\\
\small\text{G11 of Seashore} \ &\ \text{} \ &\ \small\text{Terns are Polish}\\
\small\text{P7 of Raptor} \ &\ \text{} \ &\ \small\text{Serine is American}\\
\text{} \ &\ \text{} \ &\ \small\text{A Hated Frost is American}\\
\text{} \ &\ & \ \small\text{Give Ear is Norwegian}\\
\text{} \ &\ \text{} \ &\ \small\text{An Eland is Swedish}\\
\text{} \ &\ \text{} \ &\ \small\text{Minorca is Italian}\\
\text{} \ &\ \text{} \ &\ \small\text{A Winger is Hungarian}\\
\text{} \ &\ \text{} \ &\ \small\text{Mouse Bars are German}\\
\\
\\
\mathtt{\color{blue}{ANSWER: }}  \  \ \color{blue}{\text{________}} \ &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathtt{\color{blue}{ANSWER: }}  \ \ \color{blue}{\text{________}} &\ \ \ \ \mathtt{\color{blue}{ANSWER: }}  \ \ \color{blue}{\text{________}} \\
\\
\hline
\end{array}\\
\phantom{x}\\
\phantom{x}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\text{What do I, the self-critical author, think of this puzzle?}\\
\phantom{x}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
\large\text{FINAL ANSWER: __________________________}
\phantom{x}\\
\phantom{x}\\
}$$

Comment: Just spoken with the author. He’s confirmed that the reason for the delay of edition 2 is a lack of printer ink. And definitely not because they completely forgot about the puzzle...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You, the self-critical author, think this puzzle is**

> **Good enough!**

As

> Biocryptics give 'Oldest', Chemicryptics give 'Winner' and Physicryptics give 'Nobel'. The oldest nobel prize winner is **John B. Goodenough** at 97 in 2019.

---

**Biocryptics**

> X# of word: unscramble the word to a living thing, then take the #th number of the appropriate taxonomical level — P = Phylum, C = Class, etc.

P3 of emanate

> Emanate decrypts to manatee; 3rd letter of the phylum (chordata) is O.

C6 of maniac

> Maniac decrypts to caiman; 6th letter of the class (reptilia) is L.

F5 of paroled

> Paroled decrypts to leopard; 5th letter of the family (felidae) is D.

O4 of throne

> Throne decrypts to hornet; 4th letter of the order (Hymenoptera) is E.

G11 of seashore

> Seashore decrypts to seahorse; 11th letter of the group (hippocampus) is S.

P7 of raptor

> Raptor decrypts to parrot; 7th letter of the phylum (chordata) is T

The answer is

> OLDEST for the biocryptics.

---

**Chemicryptics**

> Unscramble each word to uncover an element, then concatenate atomic numbers and take the resulting element.

Ringtone followed by an umberlily

> Nitrogen (N) followed by Beryllium (Be) gives 74 = tungsten = W

A burly lime precedes a foul rein

> Beryllium (Be) precedes Fluorine (F) gives 49 = indium = IN

A grin note

> Nitrogen (N) gives 7 = nitrogen = N

A con bar with eg. Onyx

> Carbon (C) with Oxygen (O) gives 68 = erbium = ER

Put together we have

> WINNER

---

**Physicryptics**

> Anagram the words to find a **Nobel Prize-winning** physicist, then use the first letter of their first name.

A Gerbil OBE is French

> Louis de Broglie was a French physicist (L)

The Nineties are German

> Albert Einstein was a German physicist (A)

Hulls are American

> Clifford Shull was an American physicist (C)

A Hornet is American

> Kip Thorne is an American physicist (K)

Terns are Polish

> Otto Stern was a Polish physicist (O)

Serine is American

> Frederick Reines was an American physicist (F)

A hated frost is American

> Robert Hofstadter is an American physicist (R)

Give Ear is Norwegian

> Ivar Giaever is a Norwegian physicist (I)

An Eland is Swedish

> Nils Dalen is a Swedish physicist (N)

Minorca is Italian

> Guglielmo Marconi is an Italian physicist (G)

A winger is Hungarian

> Eugene Wigner is a Hungarian physicist (E)

Mouse bars are German

> Rudolf Mossbauer is a German physicist (R)

Put together, we get the letters

> LACK OF RINGER

---

All together, the final answer appears to be

> Oldest Winner Lack of Ringer. A lack of ringer could also be written as No Bell (ie. Nobel). Now the oldest winner of the Nobel Prize was Wilhelm Röntgen who won the first one in 1901. Röntgen is famous for discovering the X-Ray. So maybe, you, the self critical author, thinks that this puzzle ought to be X-RAY-TED (haha, I’ll see myself out...)

I’m leaving the joke up there, for posterity. In reality, the

> Actual oldest Nobel prize winner was 2019’s Chemistry Prize winner, 97-year-old John B. **Goodenough.**

Therefore, what does this self-critical writer think of the puzzle?

> It’s **Good enough**!

Comment: Bio all good! My mistake for raptor, will fix. For chem you have the right elements, but you’re missing what you need to do with them. For physics, everything right except for the three giving ‘EKE’ - you’ve found 3 different ones. Try and think about how the other scientists in particular have been particular, they all share one thing

Comment: Nice! @BeastlyGerbil you’re saying that Neuron is the wrong answer? Darn, I thought I was on to something there.... and thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Neuron is perhaps one of the greatest coincidences I have ever seen :P completely unintended, the actual answer is something completely different

Comment: Also if it helps, because a lot of the physicists had multiple nationalities, I chose their nationality to be the country in which they were born, which might be why you have some slightly wrong

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil — thanks for the heads up!! Greatly appreciated. Fantastic puzzle so far :)

Comment: More good work! You nearly have chem and physics completed. I’d suggest researching Dalens name a bit more ;) Also figuring out the set the physicists have come from may help you find ‘serine’

Comment: I had Nils before and changed it LOL — is that correct? I saw the pun on rot13(ynpx bs evtbhe) and decided to take it haha... and got the physicist set @BeastlyGerbil

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I think I’m 3/3 now.... how far away am I from the final answer?

Comment: you now have everything right! The last step is to figure out what the one word is that ‘lack of ringer’ clues, it’s 5 letters and been mentioned before. Just think what ‘lack of’ and ‘ringer’ could be synonyms of. You’ll know the final answer when you get it :)

Comment: How’s this, @BeastlyGerbil?

Comment: That’s not the oldest winner of the Nobel prize ;) try searching ‘oldest nobel winner’

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I’m a dummy haha. What a fantastic puzzle! I thoroughly enjoyed this — great job! Thanks for putting up with my solving :)

Comment: there we go! You were so close it was only a matter of time :P I’m still blown away by the neutron coincidence...

Comment: Also may I edit your answer slightly so the answers at the top? The answers and puzzle is quite long so it would be good if it’s at the top :) check incoming!

Comment: The edits look beautiful — thank you, @BeastlyGerbil! Yes, I was stunned when I heard that that wasn’t correct. Great puzzle!!